# MongoDB Catalina Read and Write

Tags: mongodb, permissions

I used chown It doesn't work.

```
Bilals-MBP:~ $ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
Password:
mkdir: /data/db: Read-only file system
```

I am not able to get Read and write permission
I am using Catalina 10.15 maybe that's the problem ?

I downloaded MongoDB from Homebrew and I am able to see version on on command shell the only problem is whenever I use mongod then throws error and says Access is not allowed

Comment: I found a solution. After Catalina update Mac doesn't let us change permissions on /usr folder so we need to change directory of /data/db folders

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. After Catalina update Mac doesn't let us change permissions on /usr folder so we need to change directory of /data/db folders –

sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db

try this path if you also having same issue I have tried and worked for me.

Comment: and after you need to run mongod command with dbpath mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db

Answer (score 0):

**This is what they said in their docoumentation:**

> Starting with macOS 10.15 Catalina, Apple restricts access to the MongoDB default data directory of /data/db. On macOS 10.15 Catalina, you must use a different data directory, such as /usr/local/var/mongodb.Starting with macOS 10.15 Catalina, Apple restricts access to the MongoDB default data directory of /data/db. On macOS 10.15 Catalina, you must use a different data directory, such as /usr/local/var/mongodb.

what you should do instead

1- **Create the data directory.**

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

2- **Create the log directory.**

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log/mongodb
```

3- **Set permissions for the data and log directories.**

```
sudo chown my_mongodb_user /usr/local/var/mongodb
sudo chown my_mongodb_user /usr/local/var/log/mongodb
```

you can see here the [Full Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x-tarball/)